# RHEL Network Interface not restarting

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, bonding

RHEL 5.11
I run the restart command: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Then it just sits there until I have to force quit:

```
15:09:11 # /etc/init.d/network restart  
Shutting down interface bond0:
```

**Status:**

```
15:08:40 # /etc/init.d/network status  
Configured devices:  
lo bond0 eth0 eth1 eth2 eth3  
Currently active devices:  
lo eth0 eth1 eth2 eth3 bond0
```

The only change is I copied `ifcfg-bond0` to three new subinterfaces, `bond0:0`, `bond0:1` and `bond0:2`

Comment: Please edit and add the output of `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0` and `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

`

Comment: Issue was I had the subinterfaces setup like full interfaces. Once I removed the TYPE, USERCTL, MASTER and BONDING_OPTS properties it restarted successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `/etc/modprobe.conf` to load bonding module:

```
vi /etc/modprobe.conf
```

add following lines

```
alias bond0 bonding
alias bond1 bonding
```

Configure your ethernet interfaces ( 4 configuration files)

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX
```

like the following example:

```
DEVICE=ethX
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
```

Replace `ethX` by `eth0` , ... `eth3`

**Configure bonding**

You need to create two bonding interfaces bond0 (eth0 and eth2) and bond1 (eth1, eth3)

Create bond0 and bond1 scripts under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` same as ethernet interfaces.

```
touch /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
touch /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1
```

Type: `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0`

like this:

```
DEVICE=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
BONDING_OPTS=”max_bonds=2 miimon=100 mode=2 primary=eth0″
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.0.1
```

Edit `bond1`

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1
```

Like the following example:

```
DEVICE=bond1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
BONDING_OPTS=”max_bonds=2 miimon=100 mode=2 primary=eth1″
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.0.2
```

Restart the init

```
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/etc/init.d/networking force-reload
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP if you would take the time to explain the difference between what `restart` does and what `force-reload` does.